# Can I use a C# string format with the number of inputs decided at run time?

Tags: c#, format, string-formatting

I have a program which has various unit conversions defined in a configuration file including string formats for how they should be displayed. To display metres, centimetres, etc. only one input is required for the format, however for feet and inches two inputs are required (and potentially more could be needed for other unit conversions).

I know the number of arguments at run time from the length of a `List<>` generic containing input values. Can I then somehow input this into a C# `String.Format`?

*Clarification with an example:*

So the format defined in the configuration could be `"{0} ft. {1} in."` in the case of feet and inches or `"{0} cm."` in the case of centimetres. The code generates one or two values accordingly and puts them in a `List<float>` generic container. I then need to get the code into a `String.Format` statement, however `String.Format` does not take `List<float>` as an argument (as far as I am aware).

I know Python much better than C# and thanks to its dynamic nature I can unpack arguments in a list using the asterisk. i.e. `my_format.format(*args_list)` where `my_format` is a format string.

Is there anything similar in C#?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you want. Can you show the exact Python code that you would write to solve this specific issue? I think it would make your question more clear.

Comment: Why don't you try regular expressions (Regex) instead of String.Format?

Comment: I'm not sure how using a regular expression would help, you mean by parsing the format first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

String.Format can take an array of objects, and you can get an array of objects from a List with `yourList.Cast<object>().ToArray()`.

```
List<float> a = new List<float>();
a.Add(1.0f);
a.Add(2.0f);

string fmt = "{0} ft. {1} in.";
Console.WriteLine(String.Format(fmt, a.Cast<object>().ToArray()));
```

Or if you're using .NET 2.0 (and there may be a neater way to do this; I don't know much about C#):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static object[] ToObjectArray(List<float> a)
        {
            object[] b = new object[a.Count];
            for (int i = 0; i < (a.Count); i++)
                b[i] = (object)a[i];
            return b;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<float> a = new List<float>();
            a.Add(1.0f);
            a.Add(2.0f);

            string fmt = "{0} ft. {1} in.";
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format(fmt, ToObjectArray(a)));

            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this `.Cast` method a recent .NET addition? It doesn't appear on my List objects ...

Comment: @Brendan You could have stated which version of .NET you're using. It appears to have been introduced with .NET 3.5. Of course, you can write your own version of it.

Comment: @Brendan Do you have a `using System.Linq` in there?

Answer (score 5):

The parameters after the format string can be supplied as an object array.

Example:

```
string format = "{0} feet {1} inches";
object[] parameters = { 4, 2 };

string formatted = String.Format(format, parameters);
```

Comment: Why the downvote? If you don't explain what you think is *wrong*, it can't improve the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative

```
string format = "{0} feet {1} inches";
string[] parameters = { "4", "2" };

string formatted = format;
for(int i=0; i<parameters.length; i++)
{
    //Replaces("{0}", parameters[0]);
    //Replaces("{1}", parameters[1]);
    formatted = formatted.Replace("{"+i+"}", parameters[i]);
}
```